# Applescript repeat a variable amount of times

Tags: loops, variables, applescript

I was working on the AppleScript below and I was wondering if there is a way to make a repeat, repeat a variable amount of times. Here's what I tried to do but it didn't work. Does anybody have a solution? Thanks!

```
tell application "System Events"

    set blue to 1

    repeat blue times
        keystroke "s"
    end repeat
    set blue to blue + 1

end tell
```

Comment: `blue` is a constant from System Events' Appearance Suite, so try a different variable name.

Comment: You couldn't have possibly run that code from **Script Editor**  as it won't even _compile_ as it errors out with "**Syntax Error** Can’t set «constant appeblue» to 1. Access not allowed."